Sending value selected to backend (or $.Ajax()) different of showed at frontend
i am using the lib https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
I would like found the proprierty that send the value selected to Backend with american format.
Exemple:
JS
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.14.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      $.datepicker.regional['pt-BR'] = {
        closeText: 'Fechar',
        prevText: 'Anterior',
        nextText: 'Próximo',
        currentText: 'Nyní',
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto','Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['led', 'úno', 'bře', 'dub', 'kvě', 'čer', 'čvc', 'srp', 'zář', 'říj', 'lis', 'pro'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['dom', 'seg', 'ter', 'qua', 'qui', 'sex', 'sab'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
        weekHeader: 'Týd',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 7,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
      };
  
      $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
    
    } );
  </script>

HTML
 Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">

Alternanty, i am using the hack at onSelect function:
...

dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',  
onSelect: function(dateText) {
    // Converter a data para o formato que o backend espera
    var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var backendFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateObject); 
    $("#datepickerHidden").val(backendFormat);
},
....

it force the creation of field input hidden
<input type="hidden" id="datepickerHidden">

Shall be that exists a propriety the solve it problem?
like:
...
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',  
dateToBackendFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
...

Without the creation of hidden field in form and a function?
Of the way sugery, its not works to me. Cause it is necessary the creation of hidden field in form as already tell. But very well

i have try with altFormat : 'yy/mm/dd'  but no success

American format is mm/dd/yyyy

The datepickerHidden field needs a name attribute so the backend can get its value.

If you use altFormat you need to use altField as well. That should contain the ID of the hidden field.

ok understand, will be betther tarit it in backend with date() function. Thank you

The date() function is for formatting dates, not parsing them. You can use date_parse_from_format().
